# How do I debug Jest's preprocessor?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, grunt-jest

Occasionally I need to tweak my preprocessor.js to account for a new file type that shouldn't go through `ReactTools.transform`. I'd like to debug the calls to `process` to make sure I understand its arguments - however if I `console.log` within the method I get this error:

> Error: Attempted to send a message to the worker before the response
>   from the last message was received! Worker processes can only handle
>   one message at a time.

I am running Jest from Grunt via `grunt-jest`. Gruntfile section:

```
jest: {
  options: {
    coverage: false,
    testPathPattern: /__tests__\/.*/
  }
},
```

Preprocessor file:

```
'use strict';
var ReactTools = require('react-tools');

module.exports = {

  process: function(src, file) {
    if (file.match(/node_modules/)) {
      return src;
    } else if (file.match(/css/)) {
      return '';
    } else if (file.match(/png/)) {
      return '';
    }
    //console.log/setTimeout...console.log doesn't work
    //console.log(file);
    //setTimeout(function() {console.log(file);},0);

    var transformed = ReactTools.transform(src, { harmony: true });

    return transformed;
  }

};
```

[Relevant docs from jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html)

How can I debug the 'process' method?

(The problem I was trying to debug was requiring a css file in node_modules which was caught by the first if block and never got to the `.match(/css/)` block, but the question still stands.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into that before too and wasn't able to track down the why, but my work around was to just use `console.warn` instead.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I looked into this a little and this works because `console.warn`/`console.error` print to stderr instead of stdout (which is where `console.log` and `console.info` print). https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_error_data